# How to resolve an XMLReader warning produced by Wordpress Migrate module?

Tags: migrations

I'm converting a Wordpress site to Drupal. To do so, I need to import a wordpress export file. But whenever I try to import my wordpress export file, I get this error:

> Warning: XMLReader::open() [xmlreader.open]: Unable to open source data in WordPressBlog->__construct() (line 188 of /mnt/www/html/dev/docroot/sites/all/modules/wordpress_migrate/wordpress.inc).
>
> Exception: Could not open XML file wordpress://blog.wordpress.2013-09-05.xml in WordPressBlog->__construct() (line 219 of /mnt/www/html/dev/docroot/sites/all/modules/wordpress_migrate/wordpress.inc)

As shown in the path names within the error mesages also (ie: 'wordpress_migrate'), I'm using the [Wordpress Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate). For this module, only a 7.x version exists.

I'm not quite sure why it can't read the XML file. I've run the file through the xmllint command with no errors.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error.  I uninstalled all the WordPress migrate and migrate modules (uninstalling migrate may not have been necessary), removed from site directory and then reinstalled.

I re-installed Migrate 7.x-2.6 and WordPress Migrate 7.x-2.3-beta2+4-dev.

After that the import worked.